# Now hiring: must have the [drive] to burninate

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

It appears the [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) tag was never properly [`mount`ed](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). Because of such, it has been used improperly and has since been corrupted.

Some questions consider it the equivalent of `mount`, whereas others use it to refer to the Google Drive API.

For most questions, [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) should either be removed (and the bad questions closed) or replaced with something more specific, e.g., [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api). For questions actually dealing with HDDs and whatnot, perhaps (?) [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) should be left alone.

There are only 212 questions currently tagged with [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive), so this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: There's [hard-drive] and [hdd] for actual hard drive questions and [ssd] for solid-state drives; [usb-drive]/[usb-flash-drive]/[removable-drive]; [network-drive]; some questions might actually be about [block-device]s (not necessarily drives).